# C++ Independent references - what for?

Tags: c++, reference, alias

I read in some good C++ tutorial that independent references do exist, and act like aliasing. But... I wonder what it is made for. Why should one want to use aliasing.

Besides, some piece of code that is not clear to me:

```
int a;
int &ref = a; // independent reference
int b = 19;
ref = b;  
cout << a << " " << ref << "\n";
ref--;  
cout << a << " " << ref << "\n";
```

First, ref is a 'reference' to a. I understand from second line of code that address for ref (hence the ampershead) is a. Then, integer ref is assigned the value of b (19). First cout returns a and ref, both equal to 19. Why? Isn't integer a the address for ref? Then, decrements ref, and last cout gives two times 18. a and ref where decremented.

Only strange possible interpretation of mystery: here int& is a type in itself, 'independent reference to an integer', and this type means aliasing. Then whatever you do to ref, the same is done to a.

Is that right? But why should one need aliasing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct.  A reference is similar to a *const* pointer in many regards (e.g. modifying the value of the reference modifies the original) and you cannot bind the reference to anything else but its initial variable, but it cannot be `null` and the syntax of using it is also different (no need for dereferencing (`*`, `->`)).  Because it is not a pointer, the best description is *alias*: think of it as a different name for the same variable.

Also, if you pass a reference as a function parameter, no copy of the variable is made (like with a pointer and it pointed-to value), and any change to the reference reflects on the original variable.

There are also special rules for const references that allow a temporary value to live beyond its regular lifetime until the const reference it is bound to goes out of scope.

Comment: A reference acts just like a `const` pointer, except for the special rule about lifetime extension of temporaries.

Comment: @BenVoigt: And being guaranteed not to be null, and the nicer use syntax...,

Comment: @dribeas: A reference isn't guaranteed to be non-null any more than a pointer is guaranteed to be valid.  Either one depends on the rest of the program being correct and bug-free.

Comment: @Ben: That's true, but I think the point is that the reference *must* be bound to an instance at the point of creation, whereas that's not true for a pointer.  This saves the overhead of checking for NULL all over the place.

Comment: @Chris: I said a `const` pointer, and all `const` variables, pointers included, must be initialized.

Answer (score 3):

> Then whatever you do to ref, the same is done to a.

That's a pretty accurate way to look at it. In essence, both `ref` and `a` refer to the same `int`.

> why should one need aliasing?

One very common use of references is in passing arguments to functions. Consider the following:

```
void f(const HugeStruct& data) {
 ...
}
```

This allows the caller to pass a `HugeStruct` to the caller cheaply and with nicer syntax than when using pointers.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't make much sense in your example.  But consider this:

```
int & ri = expensive_function_call(args)->some_map[calculate_the_key()].first;
if (ri > 6) ri = 6;
```

vs

```
if (expensive_function_call(args)->some_map[calculate_the_key()].first > 6)
    expensive_function_call(args)->some_map[calculate_the_key()].first = 6;
```

Of course, you could have used a pointer:

```
int * pi = &expensive_function_call(args)->some_map[calculate_the_key()].first;
if (*pi > 6) *pi = 6;
```

By using an alias (reference or pointer), not only is the code cut almost in half, but the work the program must do when running is also cut in half (at least before the compiler starts optimizing).

Answer (score 2):

> I understand from second line of code that address for ref (hence the ampersand) is a. Then, integer ref is assigned the value of b.

I don't think you understand how references work.

```
int a;
int &ref = a;
```

The first line allocates an `int` object. This object can be referred to using the local variable `a`.

The second line has the effect of making `ref` be an alias to that same `int` object. Changes can be made to the object using either `a` or `ref`, but there is one and only one `int` object.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pick up a good book on C++ and give it a read, as there are a number of fundamental misstatements in your question.

First, a isn't the address of ref. When you use the `&` operator in your first line of code:
`int &ref = a` 
You are not setting the address of `ref` to `a`. You are creating a new variable that is an alias to an existing integer, that is, an explicit reference to `a`. This is its own operator/operation, and has nothing to do with addresses or pointers (not really).

Any time you read or write to `ref` thereafter, it's as if you were writing to a. `ref` is now another way of saying `a`, and any operations you do on it (including trying to get its address) are *forwarded* to `a`.

Comment: "You are creating a new integer". No, you are creating a reference to an existing integer.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: The wording may be off (replace `new integer` with `new reference` or `new alias`). But the point holds it has nothing to do with address.

Comment: I've revised the wording to more clearly covey the idea. Thanks @David, and Loki.

Answer (score 1):

Even when function calls aren't involved, there are good uses for alises.

You can use it to simplify a name

```
MyComplicatedStruct x;
int &ref = x.array[17].anotherarray[3];
// Do stuff with 'ref'
```

it would be a pain (and error prone!) to have to spell that out every time I wanted to use that integer value.

Another example:

```
int myFirstValue = 1;
int MyOtherValue = 2;

while(true) {
    int &value = (SomeComplicatedTest() ? myFirstValue : myOtherValue);
    // do stuff with 'value'
}
```

this would also be a pain (and error prone) to do without the reference.